# Html5 Video Play on Hover Stops Working When Dynamic Content is Loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, hover, html5-video

I have a WordPress site with video products, this code adds a function so that when the mouse hovers over the video thumbnail it starts playing, and when the mouse leaves the video it pauses. It works just fine on the initial page load, but additional content loaded via ajax does nothing.

I'm new to Javascript but I do understand why my code stops working when additional content is loaded via ajax. I just don't know how to make it work. :) I have searched for answers and came across something about using an "on" state, but couldn't figure out how to utilize that with my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
    $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
}
        });
```

I know it's not working because the new content isn't "ready" or the script isn't aware of the new content because the page didn't load. So... how do I make this work with dynamic content? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('video', this).get(0).play();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('video', this).get(0).pause();
    }
}, '.video');
```

Using **$(document).on** instead of **$(document).ready** allows it to work for any previous or future loaded ".video" classes to be modified.

The using **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** events instead of .hover